# What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive, particles, verb-stacking

What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?

For example:

> Please, help me to understand this.

or:

> Please, help me understand this.

Comment: If the question had been asked now , it would  have  faced  a lot of  criticism. did you not  consult the  dictionary  or  so on or so forth.I do not know what  research  had  the  OP  done to ask this question.There is nothing to say.Help is followed by both  to infinitive and  bare infinitive.There is much ado about nothing.

Comment: Proposed title: "_Help me [to?] understand how to use an infinitive after the verb 'help'_"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The particle "to" is not *wrong* in this sentence, but it is unnecessary. I would recommend against using it.

The phrase "to understand" can be interpreted as a special case of the infinitive; a kind of [future infinitive or impersonal future tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#Impersonal_constructions). In that context, the first sentence means, essentially, "please help me develop an understanding of this (in the future)". While that may be technically correct, it adds nothing to the meaning of the sentence.

To add some weight to my argument, the [COCA](http://www.americancorpus.org/) lists 142 entries for "help me understand" versus only 18 for "help me *to* understand". The results are similar for other constructions involving "help me ..." versus "help me to ...".

I think that the confusion stems from the way you *must* use the infinitive in other cases, for example: "I want to understand this", or "I am trying to understand this". In these cases, the particle is an absolute neccesity.

Comment: the "to" might not BE wrong but it sure feels wrong to me.  I'd strongly recommend not using it with "help me ... " .

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: I agree. It feels like a stumbling block when reading the sentence.

Comment: While in case of 'help' 'to' is merely redundant, with negative words it tends to reverse the intended meaning. "He stopped smoking" is obvious. "He stopped to smoke" - he stopped doing whatever he was doing, and began smoking instead.

Comment: This issue is not unique to the future tense - it also applies in the past and present - ""he helped me understand" versus "he helped me to understand". It is simply a question of whether to elide the "to", something which often arises in the use of the infinitive. Neither is more "correct" than the other.

Comment: However, I hear "help to" more and more often nowadays for some reason. It always sounds very strange to me, but I came here thinking I'd learned it wrong. Turned out, everyone else is using it suboptimally. Cool.

Answer (score 44):

*Help* is a special verb in that way - the *to* is usually dropped from an infinitive when it is modifying *help*.  This form of infinitive is called the *[bare infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Bare_infinitive)*:

> - The bare infinitive is used as the main verb after the dummy auxiliary verb *do*, or most modal auxiliary verbs (such as *will, can, or should*). So, "I will/do/can/etc. **see** it."
> - Several common verbs of perception, including see, watch, hear, feel, and sense take a direct object and a bare infinitive, where the bare infinitive indicates an action taken by the main verb's direct object. So, "I saw/watched/heard/etc. it **happen**." (A similar meaning can be effected by using the present participle instead: "I saw/watched/heard/etc. it **happening**." The difference is that the former implies that the entirety of the event was perceived, while the latter implies that part of the progress of the event was perceived.)
> - Similarly with several common verbs of permission or causation, including *make, bid, let*, and *have*. So, "I made/bade/let/had him do it." (However, *make* takes a to-infinitive in the passive voice: "I was made **to do** it.")
> - After the *had better* expression. So, "You had better **leave** now."
> - With the verb *help*. So, "He helped them **find** it." (The use of the to-infinitive with the verb help is also common.)
> - With the word *why*. So, "Why **reveal** it?" (Use of the to-infinitive following why is also common.)
> - The bare infinitive is the dictionary form of a verb, and is generally the form of a verb that receives a definition; however, the definition itself generally uses a to-infinitive. So, "The word '**amble**' means 'to walk slowly.'"
> - The bare infinitive form coincides with the present subjunctive form as well as the imperative form, but most grammarians do not consider uses of the present subjunctive or imperative to be uses of the bare infinitive.

Comment: Two hyperlinks to complete drɱ65 δ's answer: −−− http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv226.shtml−−− http://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/

Comment: Yes; that's why I chose the word *usually*.  Wikipedia makes a note of that as well.

Comment: Does this explain whether "The only thing one can do with a donut is eat it." is correct versus "The only thing one can do with a donut is to eat it."?

Comment: Yes it does. The Wikipedia link was changed and the page updated, so I just re-linked the page properly. Now if you click on the link in my answer, you will come to the updated Wikipedia section on bare infinitives. Among the examples, it says "As a predicative expression in pseudo-cleft sentences of the following type:
*What I did was **tie** the rope to the beam.
What you should do is **invite** her round for dinner.*"

Comment: 'The use of the to-infinitive with the verb help is also common.' does not substantiate 'Help is a special verb in that way – the to is usually dropped from an infinitive when it is modifying help.'

Answer (score 23):

I think you may find there is also a difference here between US and GB English (a field worth writing a book about!). From experience, I'd say "help...to" is more prevalent in British English and less common in the US. 
As a British translator (from German) I've sometimes had "help to + infinitive" corrected to just "help + infinitive" by US editors.

Comment: Oh, this makes so much sense now! Before moving to the UK, I'd rarely hear anyone use "help to", but now, it's everywhere, hence me looking it up on StackExchange. It's good to know I can still continue using it without the "to".

Answer (score 13):

The particle *to* is what's called a **Complementizer**. It marks the verb following as an Infinitive (in English, that's necessary because English infinitive verb forms are identical with the present tense forms -- *to go, I go; to sit, I sit*, except for the single verb *be* (*I am, to be*). More on infinitive complements [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html)

*To* is not a part of the verb that follows it, nor yet a part of whatever comes before it. It's a **particle**; one of those troublesome little words like *the, that, of, at*, etc. which English uses to decorate and distinguish its syntactic constructions, now that all its morphology's gone.

Infinitives get used in a variety of ways. One of them is as Complement clauses; these are Noun clauses that can function as the subject or direct object of a number of verbs. It's one of the principal ways we can form complex sentences. This particular chunk -- *helping their son win the fight* -- has a clause something like {their son wins the fight} as the direct object of *helping*.

As Daniel observes, *help* is unusual in that it doesn't require *to*, although it also doesn't forbid it.  Both are grammatical, and there's no meaning difference; it's just stylistic -- that means some people will feel one is more formal than the other, but won't be able to agree on which one.

- *I helped him to win the prize.*
- *I helped him win the prize.*

Different people, in different contexts, may find some distinction here, but not much.

Some other verbs that can omit *to* before an infinitive object complement include

- all modal auxiliaries (*will, would, may, might, can, could, shall, should, must*)
- *go* and *come* in certain constructions (*go be his assistant, come sit by me*)
- *do* in all its uses:

  > - *do*-support *do*: *Do you own that house?*
  > - emphatic *do*: *He **does** own that!*
  > - active *do*: *What he does is (to) read books.*

Comment: You say "This particular chunk -- helping their son win the fight -- has a clause something like {their son wins the fight} as the direct object of helping." It means help is an 'ECM' verb. But, from the knowledge I had of different types of verbs, I thought the verb " help" was an "object control"/"Di-transitive" verb. So, which one of these analyses seems correct to you:  I helped [him to win the prize]; help as mono-transitive  Or  I helped [him] [him to win the prize]; help as di-transitive?

Comment: I have no idea what you think an 'ECM' verb is, nor why _help_ taking an infinitive complement makes it one. I also have no idea what knowledge you had of different types of verbs. So I can't choose between two unknown analyses, sorry. One clue is that no verb is ever **always** of one type; there are always exceptions, idioms, and constructions where it's got a different function. This is especially true for light verbs like _help_.

Comment: Actually, I'm neither a linguist nor a student of grammar. I'm just someone who is a little interested in English grammar. There are countless number of rules and exceptions that make English very hard to understand. Anyway, just one question: can a verb, for example "convince" with its meaning "to persuade or make someone certain" or any other verb for that matter, follow different analyses depending on the context (for example, in some contexts 'ECM' and in others 'Object Control')? Thank you.

Comment: _Convince_ entails its complement and requires an indirect object. With an infinitive complement, I would consider it to be a case of [B-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), which is occasionally called "Control" in some theories. _He convinced her to marry him_ contains two references to _her_: one as indirect object of _convince_ and one as subject of _marry_. The two appear in independent predications.

Comment: Thank you for that link. That was really helpful. You say "I would consider it to be a case of B-Equi." So, how would you classify the verb 'help' in the following sentence: 'I helped him to win the prize.' or 'I helped him win the prize?' To me, it seems to be acting as 'B-raising.' what do you think? Also, could you please give me an example of a verb which can follow two different analyses (B-Equi and B-raising) depending on the context, that is, sometimes it acts as B-Equi and other times as B-raising, depending on the context of course?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be B-Raising. Look in the exercises of the link for examples of verbs that can swing both ways. The difference is about cases where the putative object can be independently required in both predications, or whether it makes sense in only one.

Comment: "Some other verbs that can omit *to* before an infinitive object complement include" should actually begin with: "Some other verbs that **must** omit *to* before..." no?

Answer (score 11):

The plain form of the verb is preceded by the particle *to* in most instances where it follows another verb, so we would have to say, for example, *Encouraging you to master Russian* and not **Encouraging you master Russian*. After the verb *help*, however, *to* is optional, and after some other verbs it is even disallowed. We cannot say **Making you to master Russian* and we cannot say **Letting you to master* Russian*.

The particle *to* is not really part of the verb at all. Not only is it not required after *help*, it is not allowed at all following modal verbs, or *make, see, hear* and *let*.

Answer (score 4):

"Helping you to master Spanish." is the grammatically complete and correct way to write it.  However, "Helping you master Spanish." is also correct - the *to* can be omitted as it is understood. This is permitted by grammar.

Answer (score 4):

The passive forms, though queried by Quirk, are used.

"I was helped clean" shows 3 Google hits.

"I was helped to clean" shows 2950 Google hits. (at my space-time coordinates)

This is how I felt the breakdown would be.

While I have no problem in accepting both "I helped clean" and "I helped to clean" as equally grammatical, I feel the bias in favour (sorry, favor) of the omission of the infinitive-marker as superfluous might be dented a little when the no-*to* advocates try to explain why *to* seems to be considered necessary in the passive.

Comment: Are you saying you find “I helped to clean the house” grammatical? ’Cause it sure ain’t to me. “I helped _him_ to clean the house” is all right, but without the object, the _to_ is quite impossible in my idiolect. “I was helped (to) clean the house” is borderline ungrammatical to me too, though. Certainly not a phrasing I would ever in my wildest dreams consider using.

Comment: 'Grammatical' is ill-defined. I would have no problem at all using/accepting in an essay 'I helped to clean the house'. ([Collins Cobuild English Usage:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/help) ) **2. 'help' as an intransitive verb**
You can also use help as an intransitive verb, followed by an infinitive with or without to. If someone helps do something or helps to do it, they help other people to do it. _The taxi driver helped to carry the bags into the hotel._

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct, although including **to** is useless. Without it, the sentence is perfectly understandable.

It's usually thought to be American (without "to") vs. British (with "to") English, but both countries use them interchangeably, so this thought is false.

Your best bet is to leave it out - your sentences will be clear and easier to understand. If you leave it in, your sentence will still be correct, though.

There are cases when you can't place **to** anywhere, like:

> Help me off the ladder, please.

Comment: Help me [[to] get] off the ladder.

Comment: Sure, you can add many useless words to make the sentence as long as possible, so that you fall from the ladder before you finish saying it.

Comment: There are no useless words. "Help me off the ladder" is a possible shorter version of "Help me to get off the ladder". The "to get" can be omitted.

Comment: It's not actually entirely false that it's a British vs American thing: counting the instances of "Help us [verb]" versus "Help us to [verb]" in BNC and COCA suggests that the "to" is used 53% of the time in British English, but only 15% in US English. So while both dialects use both forms, there is a definite stylistic bias :-)

Answer (score 3):

The *to* in *to do* is not a preposition, it is an infinitive marker. It marks the use of the [infinitive form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) of a verb.

With the phrase "helping [person] X" where X is some verb phrase (most likely an action), then the infinitive marker can be dropped.

> This inflatable is helping you swim

Is the same as

> This inflatable is helping you to swim

And

> His instructor is helping him master Russian

Is the same as

> His instructor is helping him to master Russian

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading a good while ago (I think in a book published by the Reader's Digest called *The Right Word at the Right Time*) that it is correct to use *help to* when an inanimate object is providing the help, and merely *help* when a person is providing the help. I'm not at all sure how well that advice matches actual usage.

Comment: "The glasses helped him read the blackboard" vs. "The glasses helped him to read the blackboard" -- inanimate object or no, I still prefer the version without "to".

Comment: How about "He was helped read the blackboard by having a new pair of glasses"? Incidentally, I think TRiG has got it the wrong way round with the RD citation above, and they are certainly only mentioning some authors' preferences, without themselves endorsing them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference in meaning.

**Please, help me *to understand* this**

Means, literally, ‘please get involved in my *process* of understanding (the ‘learning activity’ involved in being able *to understand’* - this).

It means ‘assist me in my journey of becoming someone who already understands’ or ‘is able *to understand*’ whatever it is).

I am looking to acquire ‘a state’ of being able ‘to understand’.

**Please, help me understand *this*.**

Focuses more on the *topic* that is desired to be understood. Whatever ‘this’ is, in the discussion.

It means ‘please help me understand *the topic* - ‘cooking pancakes’ or ‘bevelling marble’ or ‘arranging tulips’ etc.

**Examples ‘*to understand’:***

- ‘Professor - can you please help me *to understand* this  trinomial equation method?’ (a process) ‘Yes, you must add a, b, then c’.
- to bus conductor ‘can you please help me *to understand* this?’ - pointing at bus map - process of how to use it. ‘What are the yellow lines? And what do the green lines represent?’ (process) ‘Yellow lines are day buses, green are night’
- ‘Can you help me *to understand* how I get to haberdashery via art supplies and fashion, in this department store, please? (‘Help me with my process’) ‘Up to 1st floor Haberdashery, right through Art, take the lift to 3rd for fashion’.

So, the answer will ‘guide your journey’ or process. In *becoming* a person who is able ‘to understand’.

**Examples ‘understand *this*’:**

- Can you help me understand *this*? (Pointing at lumpy pancake batter) ‘well you put your milk in too soon. Should have mixed the eggs first. That’s why *this* is so lumpy!’ (Focus is on ‘this’ - the batter)
- Can you help me understand *this*? (Pointing at rough edge of marble bevel) ‘well you’ve got your chisel at the wrong angle! That’s why *this* is all rough!’ (Focus is on ‘this’ - the marble)
- Can you help me understand *this*? (Pointing at droopy tulips) ‘Well, you didn’t pierce the ends with a pin before putting them in the vase, did you? That’s why *this* wilting has happened!’ Focus is on ‘this’ - the tulips)

https://medium.com/@english_grammar/how-to-use-preposition-in-english-grammar-on-at-in-of-for-2fdb11e80029]
Look at the definition of ‘to’. While ‘to understand’ is an infinitive, the word ‘to’ is still in there, with its meaning of ‘heading towards’ something.