# "Could help avoid" vs. "could help to avoid"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Help to do” or “help do”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/help-to-do-or-help-do)

Is it correct to say:

> The right sitting posture could help you avoid back problems.

OR

> The right sitting posture could help you **to** avoid back problems.