# Help me cook vs help me to cook?

Tags: grammar

This question has been rounding my head for a while, id say help me cook but then  i think about omitting "to" which i think isn't correct. Can you give me more examples about this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24219/could-help-avoid-vs-could-help-to-avoid.  2500 questions as to to help to do.

Answer (score 1):

Context is important in English. However ignoring context, I can make this generalisation:

**help me cook**

This would be said by someone who is in the kitchen and requires assistance in preparing a meal.

**help me to cook**

This would be said by someone who is a novice cook and wants to improve their skills over time.

**Note**

Context could override the above.