# Is it correct to say "John helps you talk with people"?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive, particles, verb-stacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/help-to-do-or-help-do)

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but English is not my first language.

For me it seems that it is incorrect and it should be: *John helps you **to** talk with people*.

But I'm wondering if it's correct without the *to*?

Comment: CIRK, that would depend on if you speak American English. In England and the rest of the UK, people talk **to** each other.

Comment: _Help_ is a member of a class of "small verbs" that are on their way to becoming auxiliary or serial verbs, and [can take infinitive complements without requiring the infinitive complementizer _to_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50035/15299).

Comment: Everbody seems to be asking about infinitives without _to_ today; I'm getting tired of linking questions and answers.