# Help us decide vs. help us to decide

Tags: questions

I'm having a hard time to decide between the correct form. Is it "help us decide" or "help us to decide"? Please also state the reason for your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is that your whole sentence, or is there more to it?

Comment: _To_ is optional in an infinitive complement of _help_. This question gets asked here about once a week.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole sentence.

Comment: @John Lawler: Thanks a lot. Do you have any links to previously asked questions and more elaborate answers?

Comment: I searched in the top right corner for "user:15299 help infinitive" and 5 came up. Here's three of them: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/75190/15299 and http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50035/15299 and http://english.stackexchange.com/a/75946/15299. I'm "user:15299", btw.