# Infinitive without "to"?

Tags: grammar, infinitives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb “help”: with or without “to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Today I found this headline on bbc.co.uk

> How one family is helping their son win the fight.

which made me wonder when exactly it is allowed to omit the *to*.