# omission of infinitive marker: i.e., He'll come, if he wants (to)

Tags: grammar, infinitives, ellipses

To me, these

> *He'll come, if he wants*
>
> *He'll come, if he's able*
>
> *He'll come, if I allow him*

are simply variants of

> *He'll come, if he wants **to***
>
> *He'll come, if he's able **to***
>
> *He'll come, if I allow him **to***

in other words, the infinitive marker "to" is optional; it's omitted simply because it can be omitted. But this is *instinct* on my part; some people tell me that "to" is *required*, and omitting it makes the sentences unacceptable (if not ungrammatical).

Grammatically speaking, is "to" in the above sentences *required* or *optional*? And what's the linguistic/grammatical case for it?

(By the way, is this a case of "preposition stranding" or does it go by another name in the literature?)

Thanks in advance

edit: It's been pointed out that this question is a possible duplicate of [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without), but that question focuses on whether the to-infinitive or the bare infinitive is used after the verb "help." My question focuses on the infinitive marker "to" and what dictates/allows its omission when the infinitive itself *has already been omitted.* So, for example, instead of saying "He'll come, if he wants **to come**," is "He'll come, if he wants" acceptable or is one *grammatically required* to say "He'll come, if he wants **to**."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Comment: Related, and a duplicate of the former: [Infinitive without “to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46928/infinitive-without-to)

Comment: You're right. The question is not a duplicate of any proposed by RaceYouAnytime.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It seems like more a duplicate of the second question I linked to than the first.  But the second was marked a duplicate of the first already.  I'll retract my close-vote as the OP has explicitly addressed my concern.

Comment: It’s good that you noticed there might a difference between “… he wants… ” and “… he wants *to*… ” and why have you not first explained how you understand that difference, then why it’s a problem, please?

Comment: @Robbie. That's just the thing, I don't see a difference; as I said, to me "He'll come, if he wants" is just a variant of "He'll come, if he wants **to,**" with the same meaning. But this is instinct on my part. I've had people tell me that "to" has to be added, and when I ask "why?," what I get is something along the lines of "that's just how it is" (suggesting that perhaps there's a grammatical principle involved). In the grand scheme of things, this is not that important, but it is lingering doubt, nonetheless.

Comment: In that case, my suggestion is that take the Question to English Language Learners, which Stack is geared up and ready to explain…