# "Helping you do something" or "Helping you to do something"?

Tags: infinitives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb “help”: with or without “to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

In the phrase "Helping you to master Russian", is it correct to use "to" before "master"?