# "To like for somebody/something to be something" vs. "to like somebody/something to be something"

Tags: differences, idioms

Is there any difference between "To like for somebody/something to be something" vs. "to like somebody/something to be something"?

1. In the following case there seems to be a difference, because the former seems to suggest that one would like so for the sake of the other, and latter for ones own.

   > "I would like for you to be happy" vs. "I would like you to be happy"
2. Here, the above distinction makes no sense, since the weather is inanimate. Is the former a valid thing to say at all?

   > "I would like for the weather to be nice" vs. "I would like the weather to be nice"

Answer (score 5):

After the verb *like*, and other verbs of preference or intention, an infinitive [object complement](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/EnglishObjectComplementSolutions.pdf) clause **requires** a *For..To*-complementizer on its verb

- *I would like **to** go*, but not
- **I would like go.*

and *like* optionally **allows** a *For*-complementizer to mark the subject of an infinitive complement, if it's different from the subject of *like*

- *I would like **for** him to go* ~ *I would like him to go.*

This is all summed up in the formula below, with optional *for* in parentheses:

- *I would like (for) him to go*

Similarly,

- *I intend (for) him to become an engineer.*
- *I prefer (for) you not to leave.*
- *I want (for) you to go tomorrow.*[enter link description here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50035/15299)

Normally, though, the *for* part of the [*For...To* infinitive complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/528912/15299) gets deleted. This is not surprising, because the subject noun phrases of infinitives are often deleted, with their complementizer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is no effective difference in terms of meaning. Both can be used interchangeably, though the first sounds more formal ( this isn't to say it is formal )

Comment: Tom is British, so it's obviously not exclusively American, but it's worth saying it's predominantly an American usage. I've never heard "like for" used in British English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You obviously have never been to Wigan then Andrew!

Comment: No. The English are a nation divided by a common language.

Answer (score 0):

*To like for* has a kind of *wish* or *hope* under-meaning to it.
In other terms, when you say:

- I would *like for* you to be happy.

That obviously means that you would like that person to be happy, but it also implies that you **hope/wish** for him to be happy.

On the other hand,

- I would *like* you to be happy.

Simply means that you would like the fact of that person being happy.