# "help achieve" usage (verb licensing)

Tags: grammar, verbs, verb-stacking

When I was taught English (as a foreign language) I was told that there are two ways of putting verbs together:

- learn to play (to + infinitive)
- quit smoking (gerund)

Some verbs require one way and some require the other.

However, after some language practice, as far as I can tell *help*" is the only verb that allows omitting *to* (i.e. *help achieve* instead of *help to achieve*).

I’ve already learnt that languages and reason are most of the time incompatible, so I’m not asking for reasons why this is the case with *help* - it’s very likely that there is no answer to that.

What I’m asking is: Are there any other verbs like this?

Comment: That's a very interesting answer, @tchrist. Lots of good data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal verbs are an odd bunch.

*Do, can, must* and the like don’t use *to* before another verb:

> I can achieve
>   I did achieve *[used for emphasis]*
>   I must achieve

*Have* is used only as an auxiliary (“have achieved”) or as the phrasal verb *have to* [[ODO: sense 3](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have)] which means *must*. *Will* is similarly a future-tense indicator (“will achieve”).

Other verbs which do not allow the particle *to* are *make, let, hear* and *see.*

However, *help* **is** the only verb where the particle *to* can be included or omitted with no (or virtually no) difference in meaning.

There is some discussion at [“What is the correct way to use the infinitive after the verb ‘help’?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Comment: Thank you for this, of course I did not mean modal verbs as they fall in neither of the two patterns I described. Modal verbs are a different story altogether. But the link you gave is most educational and you did give an answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: _Do_ and _have_ are auxiliaries, like modals, but they aren't actually [modal](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) verbs; that's a very specific semantic class. You're certainly correct that they're odd, though.

Comment: As for _to_-deletion, it happens pretty frequently after verbs like the ones Bas lists that are getting used more in constructions as auxiliary verbs. Thereby they tend to lose their ordinary semantics -- the process is called "semantic bleaching", and you can see, for instance, how _have_ has mostly lost its 'possess' sense due to its more frequent use as an auxiliary.

Answer (score 3):

Bas Aarts, *Oxford Modern English Grammar*, gives the following list, which is not exhaustive:

- feel
- have
- hear
- let
- make
- notice
- observe
- see
- watch

Three of these have an effective sense (“Let my people go”, “The Devil made me do it!”, “I will have my assistant find that for you.” ). The rest are all verbs of perception (“She felt/heard/noticed/observed/saw/watched him take her bag”), which can also be used with gerunds. Some other verbs of perception which work this way are *sense*, *witness*, *perceive*, but these rarely employ the infinitive.

Comment: I never know where Bas gets his data. _Have_, for instance, can't take an infinitive without _to_. Example sentences are much more useful than lists of verbs with claimed but not demonstrated properties.

Comment: @JohnLawler  *I'll have him do it*. I missed that on his list, so I'll rewrite.

Comment: These are all [B-configuration](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) phrase structures? Some of these are likely to be Equi and some Raising; I haven't checked. There are several distinct cyclic constructions (or rules) involved, all governed by matrix verbs.

Comment: @Johnlawler  In another week I will understand what you are saying, but not yet:  I only got McCawley 1998 yesterday (on your recommendation) and I'm now halfway through Ch. II. But he's fun, and he writes actual English.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference to have a good author who sticks to the point throughout. And he is [indeed fun](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler Yah, I knew I was going to like him when I saw the subtitle of the Studies Out in Left Field. Clearly a man his colleagues enjoyed.