# Is a bare infinitive acceptable as the object of a verb?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, verbs, errors, verb-stacking

I came upon the phrase, "writing helps develop a child analytically thinking." Is this grammatically correct? Is it OK to use just *develop* instead of *to develop*?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer, because the title suggests that you're specifically curious about “helps develop,” but it's mainly awkward in other ways. You may want to change the title or the question to better reflect what you're looking for.

Comment: The quoted part aside, the question has enough errors of language. Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: The bare infinitive part of the question is interesting and possibly worth saving, as it's a bit tricky to find an authoritative answer online. The rest is problematic though. Perhaps an edit can save it?

Comment: Source stating acceptability of help + bare infinitive: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv226.shtml – this should go into one of the answers.

Comment: Please search the site before asking. The question has been asked, and answered, many times before. In fact it's in the [top 100 most frequently asked questions here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=frequent).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with *Writing helps develop ...*; but *a child analytically thinking* is strained and at the first glance opaque.

*A child's thinking analytically* makes the relationship between the child and the thinking clearer, but it leaves it uncertain whether *analytically* modifies *thinking* or *helps*. I'd rewrite something like this:

> Writing helps develop a child's ability to think analytically.

Or it may be that what you really mean is:

> Writing helps a child develop the ability to think analytically.

But I'm a writer; so I'd attribute the writing definitively to the child, and there'd be no *help* about it:

> A child who writes develops the ability to think analytically.

ADD:
I am asked to substantiate my contention that ‘*helps develop* is OK’ in the face of an alternative contention that this use is “technically incorrect” and a challenge to “find a piece of writing prior to the 19th century that uses this clause. You simply cannot verb a verb.”

Well, of course you **can verb** a verb. I just did: catenation with the bare infinitive is mandatory with the full modals. It is also permitted with semi-modals such as *need*, *dare* and *do*. And usage on the ground demonstrates that *help* must be be included with these.

I don’t believe for a minute that “correct” contemporary usage is determined by the standards of the 18th and earlier centuries; but for what it’s worth, *OED* (fasc. Heel-Hod, 1898) remarks that “the infinitive normally has *to*, which however from 16th c. is often omitted”; it offers examples from Nicholas Udall (“To helpe garnishe his mother tongue”) and Chapman’s translation of Homer (1616), which so moved Keats (“Many helpfull men, That..would then Helpe beare his mightie seuen-fold shield”). To be sure, it goes on to say that “this is now *dial.* or *vulgar*”; but the 1987 *Supplement* explicitly rescinds this characterization, and says instead that “this is now a common *colloq.* form.”

In fact, it is not merely “colloquial”; it is today perfectly acceptable in the stuffiest academic writing, as the following citations demonstrate:

> Alan Warwick Palmer. *The Decline and Fall of the Ottoman Empire*. 1994. Meanwhile, on the Salonika Front in the Balkans, the British divisions serving in General Franchet d'Esperey's multinational army would **help defeat** Germany's ally, Bulgaria …
>
> Gerald R. Ford. “Special Message to Congress Urging Action on Pending Legislation”. July 22, 1976. The Administration believes that the Federal Government has a responsibility to **help pay** the cost of educating their children, but not to **help pay** the costs of other children whose parents pay local property taxes.
>
> M.D. Rugg. *Cognitive Neuroscience*. 1997. Formalizing the theories will **help show** whether any differences are fundamental or terminological.
>
> David Bloor. *Knowledge and Social Imagery*. 1991 [The history of mathematics] must **help show** how thoughts are produced and how they achieve, keep and lose the status of knowledge.
>
> Jean O. Charney. *A Grammar of Comanche*. 1993. Such a rendering will **help demonstrate** how reference is maintained in Comanche subordination.

And perhaps of most interest to the immediate question:

> Marcia Popp. *Teaching Language and Literature in Elementary Classrooms*. 1996. When students **help develop** criteria for evaluating writing, they look more closely at their own and others' work.

Comment: I interpreted the original passage the same way, and those are good rewrites. “A child who writes ...” is good if the context is about the value of writing, but I would prefer “Writing helps ...” if it's in a context of several developmental activities, and writing is only part of the contribution.

Comment: It occurs to me that the questioner is more concerned about whether “helps develop” is grammatical, and “child analytically thinking” is a distraction. You may want to expand on the part of your answer that says “helps develop” is OK, with an explanation of why.

Comment: @BraddSzonye See my addition.

Comment: Excellent work! You might want to check out the question this is a duplicate of, in case your answer would be useful there too.

Answer (score -3):

It should be "helps to develop" or "helps the development of." The phrase "helps develop" is grammatically incorrect because its demonstrates something performing an action on a verb. For instance, you can't jump an eat. However, the pattern of "helps (verb)" is very common, so much that the technical incorrectness of it will almost always go unnoticed.

Comment: Good edit, much clearer – and welcome! Do you have any sources or evidence to back up the claim that it is technically incorrect but widely accepted? I was just looking for that myself, since I'm not actually sure whether it's grammatical.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't find a source on it, but I challenge anyone to find a piece of writing prior to the 19th century that uses this clause. You simply cannot verb a verb.

Comment: Well this isn't very specific but if you read on the different [verb types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb#Verb_types) you will notice that none of them fit the syntax of doing something to a verb. I suppose that is adequate?

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Yeah I realize that language changes and what not. And honestly, when speaking I almost always omit the "to" after help. However, when writing, I prefer that it sounds more formal.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely acceptable, you just sound a tiny bit smarter when you say "helps to develop" and even more so when you say "helps the development of."

Comment: Verbosity ("helps the development of") never sounds smart to me. "If you write the way I do, then you'll sound smarter" sounds egocentric rather than "smart", whatever "smart" may mean in this context. Shouldn't the answer be (1) **No, "writing helps develop a child analytically thinking" isn't grammatically correct**, (2) **Yes, it's okay to "use just _develop_ instead of _to develop_"**, & (3) **It may be better to redraft the sentence** as **"_Writing helps a child develop the ability to think analytically_"**?

Comment: I agree that you can't say the nonsensical ‘jump an eat’ but I must disagree with the assertion that you can't ‘help develop’ (so do [these authors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CcS4s.png), apparently). The verb _help_ is versatile enough to be applied to other verbs, and I don't think anyone sounds "less smart" when it is.

Comment: As an example, this doesn't strike me as unintelligent, or grammatically incorrect: _Some lorisids, like the potto, have evolved specialized diets, feeding on anthropoids that emit distasteful chemicals. Within the anthropoids, chimpanzees use tools to **help eat** insects such as bees and the honey they produce. Even folivores inadvertently eat thousands of insects a day._ (from "Collecting arthropods and arthropod remains for primate studies" by C. M. P. Ozanne, J. R. Bell, and D. G. Weaver). Changing "help eat" to "help in the eating of" would hardly represent an improvement.

Comment: This answer, objectively and without doubt, is wrong. As demonstrated by dozens of better answers to [previous questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without) on this subject, and by StoneyB's excellent competing answer right here on this page. −1.

Comment: Bradd, there is no official organisation that "regulates" the English language, unlike the French Academy, etc. So there is no "source". Anyone can write a book or a website and say what he likes. The BBC used to be noted for good English, but presenters on the BBC are specifically told not to use good English, as, for political reasons, the BBC has decided to go "demotic". People with Received Pronunciation, like Boris Johnson, have even been told their accents are regarded with concern on the BBC as they will "frighten the horses".

Comment: An exception is where  a pronoun intervenes. Help me find a nice book, etc.