# "Help in doing something" or "Help doing something"

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

Is the preposition **in** necessary or abundant?

To be specific, which of these two sentences sounds better/is correct?

> *This helps in achieving better fuel economy.*

or

> *This helps achieving better fuel economy.*

I know of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without]) question, however I am not sure how much it applies to my problem.

Comment: According to [OED](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/help_1), "help in doing something" and "help (somebody) do something" are preferred.

Comment: There's no saying of help sb. doing sth. Accroing to Oxford and Longman dictionary.

Comment: Hello jojo. Can you be clearer: which dictionaries don't include the construction _help [someone] doing [something]_? I agree, it sounds strange to my ears.

Comment: @Stan Can you please give the actual wording from OED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both constructions are grammatically sound.  In the first example, *in achieving* is a prepositional phrase the object of which is the gerund, *achieving.*  In the second example *achieving* is a present participle.  One spelling and two parts of speech!  *This* would have a clear antecedent in context.  For the sake of argument, lets say the *this* is referring to "careful driving."  Why not use that antecedent and make the sentence clearer and more active:  Careful driving achieves better fuel economy.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and advice - I agree in a simple case it is better solution to use only one sentence, but my previous sentence is already too long. Specifically, it says _"Today many of previously mechanical controls, like steering or braking, are becoming replaced by Drive-by-wire electromechanical systems."_ As I read again through the text, the first version, proposed as correct by @Stan, sounds better.

Comment: Then, "These systems help improve fuel economy."

Comment: I had a different idea in my head, but after trying it the way you proposed, I admit it just works better.