# How to say "I want the beer to never end" correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions

I've come across this expression and am not quite sure what it actually should be. Is it "I want the beer to never end" or "I want the beer never ends" or something else? Which is the correct way?

Comment: The correct form is "...to never end." Search for use of infinitives in English grammar. There is a different (but closely related) question that you might find interesting here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without

Comment: I'd likely say, "I never want the beer to end."  But I really can't think of a context in which I'd actually express that thought!

Comment: By the time the speaker has opened the second keg, the usual expression is "I beer the beer-end... I beer to never end... I never beer to... uh, I want beer."