# "Get help with [deciding]" or just "get help [deciding]"

Tags: verbs

I've looked at similar questions but couldn't find any describing whether "with" should be used in this situation.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without) seems the most similar, the result being that it is okay to use "to" in "help me to understand this", but it was not recommended.

Google search shows 9,830 results for "get help with deciding" and 19,400 results for "get help deciding", so it seems the usage supports dropping the "with".

Comment: When trying to gauge popularity of a short phrase, I prefer Google Ngram Viewer to search. It queries a huge corpus of books, and also gives a nice historical perspective. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+deciding%2C+help+with+deciding&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20deciding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20with%20deciding%3B%2Cc0) is your search in Ngrams. It prefers "help deciding" by almost a factor of ten, but of course this is not definitive proof of good usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with 'deciding', it is more common to say *help* ***in*** *deciding*.

That sounds more natural to my ears at least.

If comparing the search referenced in your question, *help in deciding* scores over 370,000 hits, with this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+in+deciding%2Chelp+with+deciding%2Chelp+deciding&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20in%20deciding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20with%20deciding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20deciding%3B%2Cc0) showing the other two options as well.

[image]

Comment: This really surprises me as "Help in deciding" sounds the most unusual to me of the three! (Maybe that's due to my locale.) I'm going to mark this as the "correct" answer as it's hard to argue with that data.

Answer (score -2):

Daniel, when you are using 'help' as you are here, 'to make something easier or better', you should use 'with'.

Here is a reference which should be useful,

> Help with something  - He always helps with the housework.

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1?q=help)

Comment: If I phrased my example statement as "Get help with the decision", I'd agree the "with" was necessary (I think the "the" causes the difference). However if I compare "get help playing guitar" and "get help with playing guitar", it doesn't feel right to have the "with". Whereas, if I said "get help with your guitar technique" the "with" feels right. I'm not trying to argue with the Oxford Dictionary here - I just feel that example is a little different to the one I'm asking about.

Comment: Gary, the dictionary entry you've linked to does **not** say you should use "with", it simply lists that as one possible option. It also lists "help (somebody) in doing something: *I need contacts that could help in finding a job*" and "help (to) do something: *She helped (to) organize the party.*"