# is this question grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I have been said by an english teacher that the sentence below is not correct. Do you agree? What is wrong?

What will this course help you to?

Comment: You should get a more useful response if you take the same Question somewhere such as English Language Learners.

Comment: I would, if I knew how to do it.

Comment: English Language Learners is at https://ELL.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You have been told by an English teacher that the following sentence is grammatically incorrect: "What will this course help you to?"

I agree that it is incorrect. It is fragmented. It should be structured in this way: "...help you to + base form verb (to complete the infinitive).

"What will this course help you to accomplish?" is acceptable, but the word "to" in the infinitive construction becomes unnecessary in common usage. You can simply ask: "What will this course help you accomplish?" You can substitute the verb I have offered for another base verb like "learn."

I think this post will help you: [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)