# Can we use two verbs together?

Tags: grammaticality

Can we use two verbs together?

We recognize those who **help prepare** America's future leaders for a life filled with meaning, purpose and success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without) Yes, with 'help': Help +  to-infinitive _Jill helped to wash up._ // Help + infinitive _Bill helped wash up._

Comment: I can help prepare an example with three verbs together. In the past I even may have helped prepare an example with four.