# Insert to in help prevent?

Tags: grammar

> Do you think closing international borders would help prevent the spread of pandemics?

I have a question which relates to the question above. Could we insert 'to' after help and before prevent - would help to prevent?. The current question style would seem the way to go for me, but if anyone can provide a specific answer, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Comment: Thanks for asking an interesting question. The meaning of the statement would not change. It will take a real expert to describe the parts of speech involved but the change would neither improve nor detract from the meaning.

Comment: Thank you Elliot. I'll read through the link.