# Is a 'to' needed here between the auxiliary verb and the main verb?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, ambiguity

So this post just popped on a meme site. In the comments a discussion arose is the second meaning grammatically correct. If not, what is the closest correct formulation? Perhaps including some of the bracketed terms here:`I help [others] [to] blind [evil] kids.` The `[to]` is of main interest.

[image]

Comment: No, the _to_ is optional with _help_.

Comment: @JohnLawler please post it as an answer. My intuition is the same: `Could you help me mow the lawn?` Now to think of it the main verb might be more important than the auxiliary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without) This question has been asked many times; repeated answers are unhelpful when it comes to research (searching becomes messy and tedious).