# Usage of help+to

Tags: grammar

Recently I’ve written an essay and have used help+to in the sentence:

> Preparation plays an important role as it helps to work on soft and hard skills.

My teacher said it’s incorrect to write help+to. Was it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without) (See its linked friends on the right column as well)